# No route matches {:action=>"new", :controller=>"river_station_upload"}

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I added a controller in the directory of my app with a new and create function that I will use to upload data. I didn't generate it through the terminal and there is no model or view to go with it yet. When I try to click the button that links to the new action, this is what I get

```
No route matches {:action=>"new", :controller=>"river_station_upload"}
```

whats the problem?

Comment: Did you add a route?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rails does not know for which URLs to use your controller, yet.

So what you have to do is add the routes you want it to be called upon.

Add to **config/routes.rb**:

```
resources :river_station_uploads, only: [:create, :new]
```

Depending on what your controller is supposed to "control", you might want to rename it to "RiverStationUploadsController" (and adjust respective links and buttons).